# Microsoft InfoPath Designer

Tags: sharepoint, infopath

I am trying to create a form in Microsoft InfoPath designer 2013 using a SharePoint list, and I would like to allow users to designate who approves each stage.

Does anyone have any ideas on how I might do this?

Please note that I do not have the access in my organization to use SharePoint Designer in case that was part of your solution.

Comment: Customize the workflow how?

Comment: Well I would like to add fields to the form that would designate who approves each stage.

Comment: Basically I would leave the workflow blank for the stages of approval and I don't know how to insert those approval fields into the form so when it gets submitted the form and the workflow sync somehow and it gets routed through the appropriate approval chain.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you can't use an OOTB Approval Workflow for this?
This should be a case of the user kicking off the workflow after the user starting the workflow picks who the various approvers are from the People Editor.

Comment: I think this would work as well, however I work with a bunch of scientist who hate technology so I am trying to make it as user friendly as possible so if everything is in one place it would make everyone a lot happier. Is this possible with the OOTB Approval Workflow?

Comment: Because you mentioned InfoPath 2013, I'm assuming you're using SharePoint 2013 as well. In 2013, Workflows can be launched by clicking the ellipsis next to each item in the list view, so effectively everything is contained within the one list.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a people picker column in if you wanted to add a field to the form to allow someone to put a user in manually and then read that value in during the workflow. On the downside, a people picker would allow them to choose from any person / person or group on the site. I would advise against basing a workflow on a text input like that (people picker or not).

Better to use a multiple choice field to have someone select that they'd like to go down x path or to notify a set group of people and wait for x number of responses/approvals.

Comment: I think that will work using the people picker column but how do I get the workflow to read it?

Comment: In Designer, for example: you add an email or task step and go to the addressee field (To, CC, etc) and in the select User dialog, go to the 'Workflow Lookup for a User' and then select Current Item, choose your field and hit Okay. That should cause the workflow to query that field whenever it gets to that step in your workflow.